# Self Join in Entity Framework with Max()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to fetch record from self reference table parent record contain multiple child record from these multiple record i have to show maximum offer value ,I also want to show child record from another child table too my query like this

```
var query = (from pd in _context.Product_User_Transactions_Main
             join od in _context.Product_User_Transactions_Yarn on pd.TransactionID equals od.TransactionID
                     into t
             where (pd.UserPortalID == UserID && pd.TransactionTypeID == TransactionTypeID)
             select new
                     {
                         pd.TransactionID,
                         pd.ProductName,
                         pd.Quantity,
                         pd.Price,
                         pd.TransactionTypeID,
                         pd.UOMID,
                         pd.UOM.UOM1,
                         pd.RefTransactionID,
                         pd.PaymentTermID,
                         pd.UserPortalID,
                         pd.UserSessionID,
                         pd.TransactionTime,
                         Offer = (from m in _context.Product_User_Transactions_Main join el in _context.Product_User_Transactions_Main on m.TransactionID equals el.RefTransactionID where el.RefTransactionID != null select el.Price).Max(),

                         pd.GEN_PaymentTerm.PaymentTermName,

                         Product_User_Transactions_Yarn = t.Select(p => new { p.YarnBlendID, p.YarnColorID, p.YarnCount, p.YarnDesc, p.YarnPly, p.YarnSourceID, p.YarnTypeID, p.TransactionID }),
                      }).ToList();
```

This query returns a wrong result as this query show `Max` of one record to all I want to show specific offer in front of it price. Where is my mistake? I don't know

Comment: Your Max expression `(from m in _context.Product_User_Transactions_Main join el in _context.Product_User_Transactions_Main on m.TransactionID equals el.RefTransactionID where el.RefTransactionID != null select el.Price).Max(),` seems to be a constant. It has no relation to the current row, but you compute it foreach row and you store it for each row. Always the same number. That's not the best design.

Comment: @Holger will you plea help me to solve it guide me to better design

Comment: First thing to do: define navigation properties so you don't need these explicit join statements. It will greatly simplify the code.

Comment: @samreenkhan, one needs to understand what you want, before one can help. Do this Max-thing in a separate query, if you really want a global singular result. I think you don't want a global singular number as a result.

Comment: @GertArnold I have navigation in my tables ,

Comment: @Holger i DONT KNOW much about EF I am new to it how can I MAX thing is isngle query ,I want to fetch Yarn record with bid infront of offer and bid is logical column if you come in inbox i will tell you indetail

Comment: You have navigation properties? Then use them. If you need more help you should show the code of the classes.

Comment: I use navigation property thanks for your help but i want different response it give array of the object but i want it wihout it